# Obtain a row sum based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

I am scoring a PES-brief scale at work for a study.
One of the scales requires a frequency of event: if the participant scored 1-3, +1. If 0, then +0. I need to obtain this score for each person.

EDIT: There are additional rows that I do NOT want to add. I don't want to sum 'dontadd'

Here is my dataframe sample:

```
pesb0101 <- c(1,2,3,0,1,0,3,2,1,0)
pesb0102 <- c(1,1,0,0,3,2,3,2,1,0)
pesb0103 <- c(1,2,3,2,1,0,1,0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(pesb0101,pesb0102,pesb0103)
rownames(df) <- c('person1','person2','person3','person4','person5','person6','person7','person8','person9','person10')

df
         pesb0101 pesb0102 pesb0103 dontadd
person1         1        1        1       1
person2         2        1        2       2
person3         3        0        3       3
person4         0        0        2       4
person5         1        3        1       5
person6         0        2        0       3
person7         3        3        1       9
person8         2        2        0       2
person9         1        1        1       1
person10        0        0        1       2
```

I need a score column for each person of a sum where if the score is NOT 0, +1. So my dataframe should be:

```
         > df
         pesb0101 pesb0102 pesb0103 dontadd pesbScore
person1         1        1        1       1         3
person2         2        1        2       2         3
person3         3        0        3       3         2
person4         0        0        2       4         1
person5         1        3        1       5         3
person6         0        2        0       3         1
person7         3        3        1       9         3
person8         2        2        0       2         2
person9         1        1        1       1         3
person10        0        0        1       2         1
```

I've tried a few different methods (rowSums mostly) and I think I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: `rowSums(df > 0)`?

Comment: @GregorThomas
Thanks for the neat solution. But if I wanted to use `data.table` to create a new col: `df[, row_sum := rowSums(df > 0)]` I get a warning (not error): `Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy....` How can I avoid this?

Comment: probably `df[, row_sum := rowSums(.SD >0)]`?

Comment: @Onyambu Thank u. But still the same warning

Comment: I do not kow which version of `data.table` you are using. You should consider updating it

Comment: If you want to use `data.table` I'd suggest adding the `data.table` tag to your question and perhaps mentioning `data.table` in your question. And probably remove the `dplyr` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply()` can run a function for each row of a dataframe. If you make a simple function to score the way you want, apply can do the rest:

```
score_counter <- function(row) {
  sum(row != 0)
}

# first make a new data frame with just the columns you want to add
df_pesb = df[, grepl("pesb", names(df))]
# use the new data frame to count a score for each row
df$pesbScore = apply(df_pesb, 1, score_counter)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If I want to only add the 'pesb' columns, is there a way to specify? (I edited the question - there are columns I do NOT want included)

Comment: Edited to only use "pesb" columns.